# can't configure routing in yii2 rest api angular

Tags: angularjs, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I try to add rest api in yii2-advanced for using angularjs. What I have already done

1. install angular through composer
2. add angularController for rest

   ```
   class AngularController extends ActiveController {
   public $modelClass = 'frontend\models\Tour';
   public function behaviors() {
   $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
   $behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
       'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
   ];
   $behaviors['contentNegotiator'] = [
       'class' => \yii\filters\ContentNegotiator::className(),
       'formats' => [
           'application/json' => \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON,
       ],
   ];

   return $behaviors;
   }

   }
   ```
3. Create AngularAsset and in $public js write this

   ```
   'angular/angular.js',
   'angular-route/angular-route.js',
   ```

   and change AppAsset adding my js file with angular code

   ```
   'js/app.js',
   ```
4. This is my angular routeProvider in app.js

   ```
   app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {

     $routeProvider
               .when('/', {
                       templateUrl: 'http://localhost/divnaukraina/frontend/views/angular/views/index.html',
                       controller: 'index'

               })
              .otherwise({
                      redirectTo: '/'
              });
     }])
   ```

In result everything works fine except routes. Page where angular must work
[tours page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bi1hb.jpg).
**But view from template url also renders on other pages** [main page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiaN0.png).
 I see that this is because "/" in angular routeprovider but **how to disable it**? 
And I couldn't find much detailed information about yii2 rest+angular, so any tutorials,links an so on will be very useful for me! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What was the solution: I changed `when('/'` on `when('/angular'` and I also changed link to this page in main navbar to `.../index.php?r=tour%2Findex#!/angular`. It isn't best solution but...